# Terminology for items made by recycling craft

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

*Recycling craft* is the art of making usable items from recyclable stuff.

What would be a suitable term for the items produced by this craft?

Comment: Are you looking for a word? Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: You mean like ["recycled art"?](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=recycled%20items&cp=11&gs_id=1z3&xhr=t&q=recycled+art&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=recycled+ar&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=21c0595ad86507f8&biw=1366&bih=578)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for one word that would indicate recycled art...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I teach this sort of crafting to preschoolers and I refer to it as eco-art.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard *[upcycling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upcycling)*, though it isn't exclusive to art.

> Upcycling is the process of converting waste materials or useless
>   products into new materials or products of better quality or a higher
>   environmental value.

Comment: You could come up with a noun term for the product of an upcycling process. Perhaps, ***upcycled goods / upcycled products***?

Comment: "an upcycled product is generally of higher value than the materials used to create it – metal ring pulls or can tops become jewellery, low-value coins become cufflinks" [macmillandictionary http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/upcycle.html]

Answer (score 1):

One related term is ***[altered art](http://www.instructables.com/id/Create-Your-Own-Altered-Art-In-60-Minutes/)***.  From a website on the subject:

> **[what is altered art?](http://www.altered-art.net/altered-art.html#ixzz1zAzTMiwj)**
>
> ...it involves altering or combining existing works of art to produce new pieces of artwork. However, most people would understand this expression to mean the transformation or 'alteration' of ordinary, everyday objects into artistic pieces using, for example, rubber stamps, fabric, paper, paint and fibres.

Note that altered art isn't limited to traditional recyclables.  In fact, altered artists often combine antique artifacts (such as old keys, brooches, dominoes, playing cards, daguerreotypes, etc.) to create one new art piece.  But *recycling* is a broad term; technically, it need not refer to recycling waste products.

Yet another term I've heard used is ***[garden junk](http://pinterest.com/bluepaintblue/garden-junk-ideas/)***; this refers to reusing or salvaging everyday items to create artistic or utilitarian works that are typically meant to be displayed outside, often to [accentuate a flower garden](http://www.gardensandcrafts.com/gardenjunk.html).

These two terms are more *hypernyms* than *synonyms*, but I thought they were worthy of mention.

Answer (score 0):

We use recyclable items for arts & crafts at out preschool and are trying to think of a suitable word too. How about "re-craft"?